# Como subir multiples archivos a un registro de una tabla de SQL server desde VB.NET y ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Actualmente tengo un aplicación de ASP donde realizo ciertos registros de información, a este registro le adjunto un archivo PDF, para ello almaceno el archivo en una carpeta dentro de mi proyecto y guardo la ruta en mi bd.

Mi pregunta es, en el caso de que yo quiera agregar mas archivos que debo de hacer, mi idea era agregar mas campos en mi tabla de la bd para archivos, pero vuelvo a lo mismo tendría que limitar la cantidad de archivos.
Que otro método me recomendarían, y como utilizar ese método.

PS: Tambien me gustaria aprender a utilizar el Multiple file uploader de JQuery, para realizar esta accion.

Answer (score 1):

bienvenida a SOes :D tu pregunta tiene 2 partes:

- El uso de `ASP.net` y `jQuery File Uploader` para la subida de archivos.
- La arquitectura a nivel de base de datos para el manejo de los archivos.

Te ayudo con la base de datos :D te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

Agregar un par de tablas llamadas: `Archivos` y `EnlaceArchivosRegistros` ( *considera que la palabra `Registros` hace referencia a la otra tabla que tienes almacenando la data)

La relación de estas tablas es:

- Un `Archivo` tiene uno o muchos `EnlaceArchivosRegistros`
- Un `Registro` tiene uno o muchos `EnlaceArchivosRegistros`

La tabla `EnlaceArchivosRegistros` contiene básicamente (a modo de recomendación):

- ID único.
- ID del Archivo.
- ID del Registro.
- Fecha de creación.
- Datos del usuario que lo ha creado.

La tabla `Archivos` tendrá:

- ID
- Nombre del archivo
- Extensión
- Ruta física donde se encuentra
- Fecha y hora de creación
- Usuario que lo ha creado

Con esto, tu logica de negocio se mantiene casi intacta:
la diferencia radica en en vez de pasarle el archivo de manera directa, ahora lo guardarás en otra tabla y si tienes muchos más archivos para subir, los agregas a `Archivos` y creas un nuevo record en la tabla `EnlaceArchivosRegistros`.

Ten en cuenta que para completar esta sugerencia, debes migrar las rutas de los documentos de la tabla que tienes funcionando y crear las relaciones con la tabla `EnlaceArchivosRegistros`.

La consulta cambiará cuando quieras mostrar la información, pues necesitarás incluir 2 tablas más, también en la vista deberás hacer un `for` o un `foreach` para visualizar todos los datos obtenidos de la lista de archivos vinculados.

Espero me haya dejado entender, cualquier duda/pregunta que tengas, agrega un comentario que entre todos aprendemos :D

Comment: muchas gracias,